# How to save multi JSON API response to MongoDB using Golang

Tags: go

I am fetching data from an api which comes in this format (10+ individual orders):

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "orderId": "2738183220",
            "dateTimeOrderPlaced": "2019-12-11T20:19:19+01:00",
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": "BFC0000347027892",
                    "ean": "8720165489992",
                    "cancelRequest": false,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": "2737526230",
            "dateTimeOrderPlaced": "2019-12-11T17:18:42+01:00",
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": "BFC0000346926381",
                    "ean": "8719326639581",
                    "cancelRequest": false,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this struct for that:

```
type OpenOrder struct {
    Orders []struct {
        OrderID             string    `json:"orderId"`
        DateTimeOrderPlaced time.Time `json:"dateTimeOrderPlaced"`
        OrderItems          []struct {
            OrderItemID   string `json:"orderItemId"`
            Ean           string `json:"ean"`
            CancelRequest bool   `json:"cancelRequest"`
            Quantity      int    `json:"quantity"`
        } `json:"orderItems"`
    } `json:"orders"`
}
```

But I am confused after looking at this for too long. How can I save this into MongoDB with Golang where so it will get saved as single documents? So one document is:

```
{
            "orderId": "2738183220",
            "dateTimeOrderPlaced": "2019-12-11T20:19:19+01:00",
            "orderItems": [
                {
                    "orderItemId": "BFC0000347027892",
                    "ean": "8720165489992",
                    "cancelRequest": false,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
}
```

I wrote this code:

```
func GetOpenOrder(x string) {

    apiURL := "https://api.bol.com/retailer/orders?fulfilment-method=" + x

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", apiURL, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+auth.GetToken())
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.retailer.v3+json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Read the response body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &o)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }

    c := auth.GetClient()
    collection := c.Database("goprac").Collection("openorders")
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    result, _ := collection.InsertOne(ctx, o)
    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

But right now the whole JSON response gets saved in one document. Can someone please point me in the correct direction? I have been searching SO for the last hour and found some similar questions, but still did not get the answer.

Comment: It seems like you can use collection.[`InsertMany`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.InsertMany) (instead of InsertOne) to insert multible documents. Instead of using the parameter `o`, you would need to give it `o.Orders`

Comment: I tried this but I can not give `o.Orders` parameter. Golang says: `cannot use o.Orders type ....... as type []interface {} in argument to collection.InsertManygo`. What could be the problem?

Comment: You will need to convert the types manually, as casting also doesn't work in this case. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/LnzX_nJEewq) is an example on how to do it, replace `values` with `o.Orders`